# Runnin rspec from IntelliJ

Tags: ruby, intellij-idea, rspec

I'm usally running my specs from inside IntelliJ. I've deleted my gems and reinstalled them using bundle install (due to another error) and now I'm getting an error when trying to run the specs.

I've noticed that running the specs from intelliJ it uses:

```
    from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
```

which isn't the case when running from the shell (I placed a print inside the kernel_require script check it).

Also I've see that the ruby version from intelliJ is:

```
"ruby 2.2.4: 230"
```

and from shell:

```
ruby -e 'print "ruby #{ RUBY_VERSION }p#{ RUBY_PATCHLEVEL }"'
ruby 2.2.6p396%
```

The error:

```
    /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bin/rspec /home/user/workspace/auto-test/spec/pools/pool_cg_view_spec.rb --require teamcity/spec/runner/formatter/teamcity/formatter --format Spec::Runner::Formatter::TeamcityFormatter
    Testing started at 10:21 ...
    /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': incompatible library version - /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.so (LoadError)
        from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/lib/nokogiri.rb:32:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/lib/nokogiri.rb:28:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/rspec.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `require'
        from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `rescue in require'
        from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
        from /home/user/workspace/auto-test/spec/support/capybara.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /home/user/workspace/auto-test/spec/spec_helper.rb:6:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /home/user/workspace/auto-test/spec/spec_helper.rb:6:in `each'
        from /home/user/workspace/auto-test/spec/spec_helper.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1295:in `block in requires='
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1295:in `each'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1295:in `requires='
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:109:in `block in process_options_into'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:108:in `each'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:108:in `process_options_into'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:21:in `configure'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:101:in `setup'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:88:in `run'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:73:in `run'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:41:in `invoke'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bin/rspec:23:in `<top (required)>'
        from -e:1:in `load'
        from -e:1:in `<main>'

    Process finished with exit code 1
```

If I try to run the specs from shell it will work, no errors, so I guess the problem is related to the configuration of the run but not sure what.

The run configuration which worked until now:

[image]

I've tried to remove the nokogiri gem and reinstall it, but still the same.

Any ideas?

project structure:
[image]

Comment: The shell ruby version can be changed manually (via `rvm use`) since there's no synchronisation with the SDK set in IDE. In addition, could you please attach screenshots from File | Project Structure | module in question.

Comment: by doing rvm use i get:    
Using /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4, how does it help? shouldn't I attach the SDK part of project structure? why is the module relevant?

Comment: `rvm use` + necessary ruby version will change the SDK in shell. I asked about modules since you can several modules (of different types) added to the same project and each of them might have its own SDK configured.

Comment: I've used rvm use 2.2.4, but still the error persist.

Comment: As someone using Visual Studio before, I can say that I love using guard + rspec in terminal. It doesn't require any action of me to start/stop/view tests, they just keep running in it's window on other monitor.

Comment: It's still not clear what project structure (modules) you have, is there a Ruby module with Rspec tests? If you want you can write also to rubymine-support@jetbrains.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are pointing out that you are in ruby 2.2.6 when using the console. IntelliJ is complaining about missing the nokogiri gem.

I can imagine that probably your last `bundle install` did not use ruby 2.2.4 (as used by IntelliJ) but ruby 2.2.6 to install the gems.

I recommend the following steps to narrow this down:

- verify and ensure that you are using ruby 2.2.4 on the shell (this is very important!)
- run `bundle install` to ensure all gems of your project are installed for ruby 2.2.4
- run your specs in the shell

If this succeeds then try running specs with IntelliJ. 
This should work in case the steps described above went fine.

A personal note (not knowing if it's already the case):
In my projects I always have a `.ruby-version` file in the root of my project to ensure the correct ruby version for the current project. You may even go a step further and add a `.ruby-gemset` file.

More information can be found in the [rvm docs](https://rvm.io/workflow/projects#project-file-ruby-version)

Comment: yep, I used different shell to run bundle install, not noticing that it points  to the default ruby, not the 2.2.4, thanks!